# My function in python is looping?

Tags: python, function, loops

I need to add a name and address to 'address book' in the function `add()` then write it to the file. This seems to be working fine, however, it continues to loop the input name and address which does not make any sense. I need it to go back to the `main()` after adding the contact.

```
address={}

def add():
    name=input('Enter the full name of the contact you would like to add:')
    n_address=input('Enter the contacts address:')

    if name not in address:
        address[n_address]=name
        writeFile()
    else:
        print('That name has already been entered.')

    return address

def find():
    name=input('Enter the name of the contact you would like the address for:')

    if name in address:
        n_address=address.get(name)
        print(n_address)
    else:
        no=input('That name is not in the address book yet, would you like to add it? y/n:')
        if no != 'n':
            add()

def a_print():
    if ('AddressBook.txt'):
        read_file=open('AddressBook.txt','r')
        mylist=read_file.readlines()

    for line in mylist:
        if line != '\n':
            n_address, name = line.split(':')
            name = name.rstrip()
            address[n_address]=name

    return address
    print(address)

def readFile():
    pass

def writeFile():
    write_file=open('AddressBook.txt','w')

    for (k,v) in address.items():
        string=k+':'+v+'\n'
        write_file.write(string)

    write_file.close()

def main():
    print('           Personal Address Book')

    print('0 - Quit\n'
          '1 - Add a New Contact\n'
          '2 - Find Contacts Address\n'
          '3 - Print Entire Collection\n')

    choice=input('\n Choose a number corrosponding to the option above.\n')

    while choice != '0':
        if choice == '1':
            add()
        elif choice == '2':
            find()
        elif choice == '3':
            a_print()

main()
```

Comment: What do you expect `while choice != '0'` to do?

Comment: Your prompt is outside of the `while` loop so there is never a chance for the user to ask to quit.

Comment: right i understand that particular loop, how ever i am referring to the function add(). basically the while loop is an option menu. each option leads to a function. option 1 is the add() which works but then in the function itself it loops which is what i don't understand.

Comment: Personal Address Book
0 - Quit
1 - Add a New Contact
2 - Find Contacts Address
3 - Print Entire Collection


 Choose a number corrosponding to the option above.
1
Enter the full name of the contact you would like to add:frank
Enter the contacts address:111
Enter the full name of the contact you would like to add:

Comment: i don't want it to ask me to add an additional name i just want to add one name then return to the menu

Answer (score 0):

You need to unset choice somehow.  Choice never resets and you're stuck in the while loop.  Bring the prompting logic inside the loop and it should fix your problem:

```
choice = 1 # This will get reset, anything but 0 is fine.

while choice != '0':
  print('0 - Quit\n'
  '1 - Add a New Contact\n'
  '2 - Find Contacts Address\n'
  '3 - Print Entire Collection\n')
  choice=input('\n Choose a number corrosponding to the option above.\n')
  if choice == '1':
      add()
  elif choice == '2':
      find()
  elif choice == '3':
      a_print()
```

Comment: It's the string `'0'`, not the number `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice is outside the while loop. The choice is made before the loop and then carried in. Once inside the loop you don't have a mechanism to ask for another choice, so the choice always stays as add. At the end of the loop before it finishes, you need to ask for a new choice:

```
print('0 - Quit\n'
      '1 - Add a New Contact\n'
      '2 - Find Contacts Address\n'
      '3 - Print Entire Collection\n')

choice=input('\n Choose a number corrosponding to the option above.\n')

while choice != '0':
    if choice == '1':
        add()
    elif choice == '2':
        find()
    elif choice == '3':
        a_print()
    print('0 - Quit\n'
          '1 - Add a New Contact\n'
          '2 - Find Contacts Address\n'
          '3 - Print Entire Collection\n')
    choice=input('\n Choose a number corrosponding to the option above.\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the menu inside the while loop

```
def main():

    print('           Personal Address Book')


    while True:

        print('0 - Quit\n'
          '1 - Add a New Contact\n'
          '2 - Find Contacts Address\n'
          '3 - Print Entire Collection\n')

        choice=input('\n Choose a number corrosponding to the option above.\n')

        if choice == '0':
            break
        elif choice == '1':
            add()
        elif choice == '2':
            find()
        elif choice == '3':
            a_print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the menu to inside the `while choice != '0':` loop.

```
choice = '1'
while choice != '0':

    print('0 - Quit\n'
      '1 - Add a New Contact\n'
      '2 - Find Contacts Address\n'
      '3 - Print Entire Collection\n')

    choice=input('\n Choose a number corrosponding to the option above.\n')

    if choice == '1':

        add()

    elif choice == '2':

        find()

    elif choice == '3':

        a_print()
```

This way it won't keep looping the users first choice and will prompt them to select another option.